# Transform and feed data into DESeq2 with DESeqDataSetFromMatrix

Tags: r, rna-seq, deseq2

There is a `normalized` expression matrix. I split it into two and want to do `DE` on the two cells' subsets. I am having trouble transforming it into the format that `DESeq2` would accept. The function that I would think I need to use is the following:

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = cts,
                          colData = coldata,
                          design= ~ batch + condition)
```

It would be perfect if I could somehow feed two matrixes separately, but I can not find it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I tried the following:

```
cells <- c(cell_names, cell_names_cyt)
groups <- c(rep("NE", times=length(cell_names)), rep("EX", 
times=length(cell_names_cyt)))

colData <- data.frame(
  Cells <- cells,
  Groups <- groups
)

dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = df,
                          colData = colData,
                          design= ~ Groups)
```

But getting the error:

> Error in DESeqDataSet(se, design = design, ignoreRank) : 
>     some values in assay are not integers

Of course, they are floats since I already normalized the matrices.

> Update

I did the following since I am using `Seurat`:

```
df <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(seurat_object@raw.data))
df <- df[,colnames(df) %in% cells]
```

But then the following:

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = df,
                          colData = colData,
                          design= ~ Groups)
```

Gave me an error:

> Error in DESeqDataSet(se, design = design, ignoreRank) : all variables in design formula must be columns in colData

Comment: Don't input normalized counts, use raw counts.

Comment: Yeah, I used raw counts retrieved from Seurat, but then got another error.

Answer (score 1):

> Error in DESeqDataSet(se, design = design, ignoreRank) : all variables
>   in design formula must be columns in colData

I think that means just what it says...you don't have a "Groups" column in coldata.  Did you spotcheck your ColData data frame to make sure it looks the way it should?

```
> cells <- c("1","2","3")
> groups <- c("a", "b", "c")
> test <- data.frame(Cells <- cells, Groups <- groups)
> test
  Cells....cells Groups....groups
1              1                a
2              2                b
3              3                c
> colnames(test)
[1] "Cells....cells"   "Groups....groups"
```